# what does this mean in Renviron?

Tags: r, unix

I see a lot of stuff in my Renviron file like

```
MAKE=${MAKE-'make'}
## Prefer a POSIX-compliant sed on e.g. Solaris
SED=${SED-'/usr/bin/sed'}
## Prefer a tar that can automagically read compressed archives
TAR=${TAR-'/usr/bin/tar'}

## System and compiler types.
R_SYSTEM_ABI='macos,gcc,gxx,gfortran,gfortran'

## Strip shared objects and static libraries.
R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB=${R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB-'strip -x'}
R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB=${R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB-'strip -S'}

R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/aarch64-apple-darwin20-library/4.1'}
```

And I'm confused. Why do we write `R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/aarch64-apple-darwin20-library/4.1'}` instead of `R_LIBS_USER='~/R/aarch64-apple-darwin20-library/4.1'`? What does the former even mean?

Comment: The first one looks up the current setting for R_LIBS-USER and appends a subdirectory, while the second one hard codes the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an example of POSIX shell variable expansion.  The pattern `${variable-default}` will expand to the value in `variable` if it is set, or it will expand to the `default` value if not.  This is described in the `?Startup` help page.

So you can set an environment variable named `R_LIBS_USER` to use your own customized libs, otherwise R will use `~/R/aarch64-apple-darwin20-library/4.1`, and similarly for the other variables.